# grub 2 fails to boot win 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, system-installation

I have just installed kubuntu 13.10 on a windows 7 machine but now grub is unable to find the win 7 boot option..:(
I have installed and ran boot-repair to generate the diagnostic link.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7370400

The steps i took in creating the kubuntu installation can be found here .

[How do I partition my Hard drive to install Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182794/how-do-i-partition-my-hard-drive-to-install-kubuntu)

Please can you help me reconfigure grub2.0 to find the win 7 boot option.

regards
peter

Comment: It looks to me that you have a GPT partition table. Correct me if I am wrong. Did you select the options for EFI?

Comment: apologies sandman 007 but i can remember no option during the kubuntu installation where I may have specified EFI. Actually Im not quite sure what either GPT or EFI signify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either left Windows hibernated or it needs chkdsk.
Partition table says sda1 is NTFS, but none of the Linux tools can mount it to see that it is a bootable partition. If it needs chkdsk or if hibernated, the NTFS driver will not mount a NTFS partition to prevent further damage.

You need a Windows repair disk and run chkdsk on sda1.

You may be able to reinstall a Windows boot loader to the MBR temporarily to boot Windows and see if you can use f8 to get into its own repair console.

But then you have to reinstall grub after fixing Windows. Grub really only boots working Windows.

How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

After fixing Windows and restoring grub boot loader in Kubuntu run this to add Windows to grub menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7389026/

Comment: I managed to create a win 7 repair cd and ran the fixboot & fixmbr commands as described  here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader. I failed in my attempt to run chkdsk however . could you provide a step by step for me if possible. regards

Comment: I thought the old XP command chkdsk c: /r worked. This: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714.aspx OR: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/using-windows-7-how-do-i-run-chkdsk/a68b3e4d-1a42-e011-9767-d8d385dcbb12

Comment: Im afraid that running CHKDSK C:/r via the win 7 repair command prompt returns an error informing me that the  C filesystem is classed as RAW and therefore unable to be processed using chkdsk. Is it possible that NTFS drivers are not installed when running the win7 repair disk?

Comment: Im considering running testdisk on sda1 to attempt a recovery . What do you think ?

Comment: Partition table says it is NTFS, script shows BS boot sector is NTFS, but it cannot mount it. That usually is chkdsk or hibernation, but could be many other Windows issues.  RAW usually means the BS or partition table is not NTFS or it in effect is not formatted.

Comment: so would you recommend  running testdisk to complete a NTFS Boot sector recovery. Or should I hold off for now and do more research.  TestDisk reports on completion of analysis  that The first partition is listed twice which points to a corrupted partition or an invalid partition table entry. Additionally reports "Invalid NTFS boot" which points to a faulty NTFS boot sector.

Comment: I do not know about invalid entry. But testdisk will create a new BS boot sector. But the BS that testdisk creates is a XP type that has in it to boot with ntldr. But if you run ckdsk from Windows 7 it should convert it. Or run bootsect.exe to write a correct boot sector from Windows.