# How to install Ubuntu GNOME on my HP Pavilion UEFI-based laptop running Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, windows-10

I bought this laptop over a year ago and it came with Windows 8 at the time, but I've since updated it to Windows 10 using the Insider Preview program. I would like to install Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 alongside Windows, but I've never dual-booted Linux and Windows on a UEFI system. Normally, I've delt with PCs that have BIOSs instead. I set aside 80GBs of unallocated space for the installer to use.

I've got a live USB set up and when I boot it up, I choose the UEFI version of the USB drive. I don't know much about the UEFI system, so I figured that would be the right way to go.

When I open the installer and I get to the **Installation Type** section, I don't know whether to choose **Install Ubuntu GNOME alongside Windows Boot Manager**, or choose **Something Else**. I've tried looking on multiple sources via Google searches, but the results are not consistent, so I'm not definitively sure which way is the best way to go.

Here's a picture of all the partitions I've got installed in GParted.

[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcZdp.png)

P.s: I've also disabled Fastboot in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

When dual-booting and starting with an existing Windows installation, it's almost always best to install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows. In your case, since you've got Windows in EFI mode, you should install Ubuntu in the same way. From your description, it sounds like you're starting the process correctly.

Your partition layout looks complex, so I'd avoid the automatic options and use "Something Else" for partitioning. Several questions and answers on this site touch on how to do this, including:

- [Choosing "something else" when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748302/choosing-something-else-when-installing)
- [Should I choose to Install alongside windows 8 or something else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412319/should-i-choose-to-install-alongside-windows-8-or-something-else)
- [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

One thing about your partitions jumps out at me: You have several small (465-841MiB) NTFS partitions following the unused space where you presumably intend to install Ubuntu. The first of those is over half used, but the other two are almost entirely unused. You might want to figure out what these partitions are, since you might want to delete or re-purpose one or more of them if they aren't in active use. Deleting such a partition might then necessitate moving another partition if you want to consolidate all the free space.